# Create a column ranking order of records by date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, lines-of-code

Imagine I have the following dataframe with employees, their contract type (values could be Employee, Contractor and Agency). Also, one person can have more than 1 contract as you could see in the dataframe example below:

```
ID      Name    Contract    Date
10000   John    Employee    2021-01-01
10000   John    Employee    2021-01-01
10000   John    Employee    2020-03-06
10000   John    Contractor  2021-01-03
10000   John    Agency      2021-01-01
10000   John    Contractor  2021-02-01
10001   Carmen  Employee    1988-06-03
10001   Carmen  Employee    2021-02-03
10001   Carmen  Contractor  2021-02-03
10002   Peter   Contractor  2021-02-03
10003   Fred    Employee    2020-01-05
10003   Fred    Employee    1988-06-03
```

I need to find a way that, per each unique ID, and each unique Contract Type, it created a column named "Order" that would rank, starting with 1 on the oldest contract, each of the contract types each ID have.If the date is the same, the rank order does not matter. This would result on the following dataframe:

```
ID      Name    Contract    Date        Order
10000   John    Employee    2021-01-01  1
10000   John    Employee    2021-01-01  2
10000   John    Employee    2020-03-06  3
10000   John    Contractor  2021-01-03  2
10000   John    Agency      2021-01-01  1
10000   John    Contractor  2021-02-01  1
10001   Carmen  Employee    1988-06-03  1
10001   Carmen  Employee    2021-02-03  2
10001   Carmen  Contractor  2021-02-03  1
10002   Peter   Contractor  2021-02-03  1
10003   Fred    Employee    2020-01-05  2
10003   Fred    Employee    1988-06-03  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach: You first sort `df` using [**`df.sort_values()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and finally use [**`df.groupby().cumcount()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```py
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Contract', 'Date'])
df['Order'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract']).cumcount() + 1
print(df)
```

---

```
       ID    Name    Contract        Date       Data  Order
4   10000    John      Agency  2021-01-01 2021-01-01      1
3   10000    John  Contractor  2021-01-03 2021-01-03      1
5   10000    John  Contractor  2021-02-01 2021-02-01      2
2   10000    John    Employee  2020-03-06 2020-03-06      1
0   10000    John    Employee  2021-01-01 2021-01-01      2
1   10000    John    Employee  2021-01-01 2021-01-01      3
8   10001  Carmen  Contractor  2021-02-03 2021-02-03      1
6   10001  Carmen    Employee  1988-06-03 1988-06-03      1
7   10001  Carmen    Employee  2021-02-03 2021-02-03      2
9   10002   Peter  Contractor  2021-02-03 2021-02-03      1
11  10003    Fred    Employee  1988-06-03 1988-06-03      1
10  10003    Fred    Employee  2020-01-05 2020-01-05      2
```